# Why setInterval function is not working properly in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, microsoft-edge, scrollto

I made a button which when clicked scrolls down users web client for 850px.It works as expected on Chrome and Firefox,scroll time is linear and identical.However on Edge it starts with the same pace and then after aprox. 200px drastically slows down scrolling animation.
Here is the code:

```js
"use strict";
 function scrollslowly(){
     var i=0;
     var x=setInterval(scrolldown,1);
     function scrolldown(){
         if(i<850){
              window.scrollTo(0,i++);
         }
         else {clearInterval(x);}
     }
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="scrollslowly()">scroll slowly</button>
<div style="height: 840px">div element 1</div>
<hr>
<div style="height: 840px">div element 2</div>
```

Comment: `clearInterval(scrolldown)` doesn't look right. Did you mean `clearInterval(x)`?

Comment: Yeah,thanks, i wouldnt notice it if you havent mentioned it.Just edited the code nothing changed on Edge

Comment: which edge? the microsoft one or the one based on chrome?

Comment: try `function scrollslowly() {
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout(scrolldown, 1);
    function scrolldown() {
        if (i < 850) {
            window.scrollTo(0, i++);
            setTimeout(scrolldown, 1);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rx4tth

Comment: Tried it.Still experiencing the same problem though.

Comment: so, is it microsoft edge or microsoft chrome edge? if it's the old microsoft edge, then don't worry about it, it won't be around too much longer to be a pain in the backside like all of microsofts browsers

Comment: Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by old.I installed windows 10 in 2019 and got Microsoft Edge with it i did all updates.

Comment: don't worry about it - microsoft new edge is chrome with a dash of lipstick, and behaves like chrome - stop writing code for dead browsers :p

Comment: current microsoft edge browser is chrome with lipstick - so should behave like chrome - the "old" microsoft edge is not worth writing code for

Comment: I suppose that the amount of people using edge is the same as amount of people using Myspace.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem in MS Edge under windows 10 1903 (March 2019) build. The version shown for edge (shown under ... > settings> about this App) is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362

Comment: Then it may even be possible that something outside that code  is causing trouble.I have sticky menu as well which after being scrolled for its height becomes sticky with adjusted height.I thought it may be causing trouble,so i removed the code still getting the same behaviour.It starts with normal pace and then drastically slows down.It works normal on chrome and mozilla but something strange is happening on edge.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in Edge with the code snippet. The scroll speed and time are the same in Edge and Chrome. I tested with the same Edge version as traktor53's. Is there any error in console in your Edge? Can you reproduce the issue with only the code snippet you providing in the thread? If not, please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I have this same issue on a Surface laptop (only) using MS Edge (the latest version) on the current version of Windows 11.  A div of vertically scrolling text using similar code to above.  For several seconds the text scrolls upward at a normal rate, then slows to a pixel or two every second (very slow).  I have tried it on the latest Edge on two other Win11 machines and they are fine.  It also works properly in Firefox and Chrome on the Surface .  I even reset Edge's settings to default and it still occurs.